# What should I do for deleting data from different mysql table with foreign key in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Table: keyword  ( id, term)

Table: ob_key ( id, user_id, key_id)

(ob_key.key_id) references (key.id)

I want to delete (ob_key.id) based on (ob_key.user_id) and keyword (term), so create a select statement below, but it is not working

```
<?php

$term=strtolower($_POST['term']);
$user_id=$_POST['users_id'];

$stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM ob_key WHERE user_id=:user_id AND key_id=(SELECT id FROM keyword WHERE term=:term)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":term",$term);

            $stmt->execute(); 
?>
```

Comment: you got some error? And your user_id and term exists in the table?

Comment: your term has String values

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's not working?

Comment: it doesn't show any error in exception, it just won't delete the data. If I use key_id="134" a specific number, it works, but if I use =(select from) the code above, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM ob_key WHERE user_id=:user_id AND key_id IN (SELECT id FROM keyword WHERE term=':term')");
```

the problem is that we must use IN instead of equals (=)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. IN works fine, = is OK too. The problem is neither = or IN, I have to trim my $_POST. Thanks for your time.